# System.MissingMethodException when creating table in sqlite-net-pcl

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sqlite-net-pcl

When calling for this function to create the database, an error occurs **System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: int SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable(SQLite.CreateFlags)'**
This is where it throws the error during the call for `database = new TransmodLocalDB();`

App.xaml.cs

```
public static TransmodLocalDB Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new TransmodLocalDB(0);
                }
                return database;
            }
        }
```

And here is the creation of the tables and the call could not proceed to here.

TransmodLocalDB.cs

```
public TransmodLocalDB()
        {
            try 
            {
                database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
                // create the tables
                database.CreateTable<Account>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<Driver>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<Job>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<TransportLeg>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<Notes>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<ImageNote>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<Sync>(CreateFlags.None);
                database.CreateTable<Enums>(CreateFlags.None);
            } catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                var me = ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

The exceptions throws before it can create the tables.
Used this library `sqlite-net-pcl by Frank A. Krueger latest version 1.6.292`

Comment: turn on the linker only for runtime and delete the bin obj and restart VS and try again , it must work.

Comment: Thank you and I already fixed this.

Comment: Did you fixed this way or some other way?

Comment: Fixed this in other way

Comment: Could you please tell how, struggling with same issue